# Ubuntu 18.04 failed to start on HP Pavillion g6 Win7

Tags: 18.04, hp-pavilion

I am very VERY new to Ubuntu, Linux, etc. I had an old HP Pavillion g6 laptop that wouldn’t run windows anymore so I thought it would be a good learner comp for this. I was able to install Ubuntu 18.04 and replace windows, but when I restarted it failed to boot. The line that failed was: Failed to start Load/Save Screen Backlit Brightness. I have looked up how to fix this, and while there are great answers of how to change how something is written, it is beyond my level of understanding. Can I fix this? Should I use an older version of Ubuntu?

Comment: If it "wouldn’t run windows anymore", why do you think it would run much more heavy modern Ubuntu?

Comment: From what I had read online, it appeared to be a way to bring an old laptop back to life when windows stopped working, I thought I would give it a try. I guess it’s a no go then? I was able to boot it off of a USB and use it. It was when i restarted the computer after installing that I saw the failure (sorry if that is the wrong term).

Comment: Most likely the HDD is almost dead.

Comment: Well, shoot. That would make sense. Is there a lighter version I could try (until my comp totally dies)?